# Can I achieve this with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a small **shadow** to the right of my border similar to the image below.

Can this be achieved with css?

[image]

CSS:

```
.border {
    border-right: solid 1px #ddd;
}
```

Comment: Yes. This can be achieved. http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/

Comment: You can use CSS3 box-shadow. There's even an inset property if you want the shadow on the inside of the container.

Comment: Can you share with us what you've tried, where you've looked for info and why it didn't meet your needs, etc? This will make it easier (and more fun!) for us to help you.

Comment: You can also use a `background-image` and repeat it if your audience isn't expected to have access to a CSS3-compatible browser.

Comment: You should consider using an image. Like a 1px height image that repeats. Pro is that all browsers will support it.

Comment: I don't think he wants to use images, he is looking for a css answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS3 `box-shadow`. [Here's a nice little playground for you to doodle in.](http://box-shadow.info/)

Bear in mind, [browser support isn't particularly strong here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow).

Comment: ahh, very nice.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can try the `-moz-box-shadow` features, although I don't know if these are cross-browser compatible yet. `box-shadow` is another way to ensure that it is cross browser compatible (along with the `-webkit-box-shadow`). To be safe, I usually use them all.

For details on how to use them, check out http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/

ie..

```
.border {
box-shadow: 0 5px 0 0 #000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 0 0 #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 0 0 #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the [box-shadow](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/) CSS3 attribute.

```
#Example_H {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset -5px -5px 5px #888;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset -5px -5px 5px #888;
  box-shadow: inset -5px -5px 5px #888;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="container"></div>​

#container{
    background: #e9e9e9;
    height: 200px;
    width: 50px;
    box-shadow: -5px 0 5px #888;
    margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
}​
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/mEHTU/15/)

As already mentioned by others this will work fine in chrome/FF but unlikely in IE.

Answer (score 0):

```
.sidebar{
    width:200px;
    height:500px;
    background:#F0F0F0;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 8px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 8px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}​

<div class="sidebar">

</div>​
```